# TSQL loop WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: t-sql, while-loop, exists

I have tables for roles and permissions with a join table called role_permissions.

For every role, I want to insert a new permission if that role does not already possess the permission. The problem with my loop is that only a single row (role) is ever updated. The loop does not appear to properly re-evaluate the subquery (which finds the first role that does not have the permission) on each loop

```
DECLARE @role_id INT

SET @role_id = (SELECT TOP 1 role_id FROM p_role_permissions WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM p_role_permissions WHERE permission_id = 57))

WHILE @role_id IS NOT NULL
BEGIN

INSERT INTO p_role_permissions (role_id, permission_id) VALUES(@role_id, 57)
-- does not appear to evaluate correctly (works only on the first loop)
SET @role_id = (SELECT TOP 1 role_id FROM p_role_permissions WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM p_role_permissions WHERE permission_id = 57))

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop. You can do this in one insert statement.

```
;WITH RolesToAdd
     AS (SELECT role_id
         FROM   p_role_permissions /*Would be better to use a roles table here */
         EXCEPT
         SELECT role_id
         FROM   p_role_permissions
         WHERE  permission_id = 57)
INSERT INTO p_role_permissions
            (role_id,
             permission_id)
SELECT role_id,
       57
FROM   RolesToAdd
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok making some assumptions here, but I believe you could just do this:

Get the roles that do no have permission 57:

```
INSERT INTO p_role_permissions (role_id, permission_id)
   SELECT
       rp.Id,
       57
   FROM
       (SELECT
            r.Id
         FROM roles as r
         LEFT OUTER JOIN p_role_permissions as rp
         ON r.Id = rp.Role_Id AND rp.Permission_Id = 57

         WHERE r.Id IS NULL) as nr
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO p_role_permissions (role_id, permission_id) (SELECT role_id, 57 FROM p_role_permissions WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM p_role_permissions WHERE permission_id = 57))
```

Comment: Your `NOT EXISTS` sub query is not correlated in any way to the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

```
MERGE INTO p_role_permissions 
USING (SELECT DISTINCT roleid, 57 FROM p_role_permissions) AS src  
ON (p_role_permissions)  
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
    INSERT p_role_permissions (role_id, permission_id)
    VALUES (role_id, 57);
```